# Error installing compass ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension in MAC OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, compass

I have a problem with Compass, when I want to install it, I have this message error

```
sh-3.2# gem install compass --source http://rubygems.org
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing compass:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20160524-691-6ackvr-0.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/ffi-1.9.10 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/extensions/universal-darwin-10/1.8/ffi-1.9.10/gem_make.out
```

Ruby is installed

```
sh-3.2# ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

The version of OS is 10.6.8

Comment: The first thing I would try is upgrading the ruby version, if possible. `1.8.7` is *old!*

Comment: Also, does the file `.../ruby.h` exist on your computer? If not, you probably need to install the ruby *development* libraries. (Which, again, could easily be solved as part of a ruby version upgrade.)

Comment: ruby.h exists.

I try the update the Ruby Version but tow fails "Git is unavailable", I try to install but is not compatible with my version of OS (I can't upgrade the OS) and /usr/local/Library/brew.sh: line 140: /usr/bin/xcode-select: No such file or directory and Failed during: /usr/local/bin/brew tap homebrew/core